# Pattern counter in fasta file

Tags: regex, perl, awk, counter, fasta

I am trying to get the count of matching patterns in the fasta file. I am starting from a fasta file containing 57k sequences. I want to pull out the count of my matching pattern sequence and show the starting position of the pattern

Input file:

```
chr1 ATTAG**CAGAT**GTGACGTCGATGT**CAGAT**TG

chr2 TGAGCTG**CAGAT**CGTAGATGATTCTGCAGGAACCT

chr3 TCTTT**CAGAT**GCCTCTG**CAGAT**TC
```

Searching pattern "CAGAT"

Output Required:

chr   Count  P1   P2

chr1 -- 2 -- 6 -- 25

chr2 -- 1 -- 8

chr3 -- 2 -- 6 -- 19

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried.? You are telling about the genome sequence if you parse the whole sequence in a single variable, it will go to out of memory. You should parse the file line by line.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I dont want to parse the sequence, i just want the number of matching pattern present in each chromosome.

Comment: Please show you actual input or link the NCBI URL.  I didn't understand `chr1 -- 2 -- 6 -- 25` this output.

Comment: I am searching the pattern in each chromosome, in chromosome 1 i got 2 hits of my pattern amd position of those hits are 6th position and 25th position, like this in chomosome 2 , i got 1 hit of my pattern in 8th position, like wise further..

Comment: I understand "Count" but what the heck are "P1" and "P2" in your output?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your file to be seperated with tab as delimiter.

```
   open(my $in,"<:utf8","in.txt") or die "Cannot open FILE in.txt : $!\n";

    while(<$in>) {
        chomp($_);
        my $cur = $_;
        #$print "iam $cur\n";
        my @tt = split(/\t/,$cur);  #assuming you file tobe tab seperated
        my $s1 = $tt[1];
        my $s2 = "CAGAT";
        my @val;
        print "$cur\t";
        while ($s1 =~ /($s2)/g) {
            push(@val,  $-[0]); #$-[0] is the offset of the start of the last successful match.
        }
        my $count = @val;
        @val = join(",",@val);
        print " No of Matches:$count Starting positions:@val\n";

    }
```

**in.txt**

```
chr1    ATTAG**CAGAT**GTGACGTCGATGT**CAGAT**TG

chr2    TGAGCTG**CAGAT**CGTAGATGATTCTGCAGGAACCT

chr3    TCTTT**CAGAT**GCCTCTG**CAGAT**TC
```